# How to automatically include my helper file in model in Joomla?

Tags: joomla2.5

I am wondering how to automatically include helper into to the all models files of the component, that i only need to create object from helpers class in models files?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `require_once`, and use the proper Joomla methods for including helper classes

```
JLoader::register('ClassName', 'path_to_class');
```

Put this snippet in the beginning of your component entry controller. Joomla will then autmotically load the class only when it's needed.

By using the regular PHP `require_once` you will slow down your code, since the file will instantly be loaded into memory, even if it's not needed.